# How to access network player from internet

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer, unet

I just followed a guide about [basic UNet tut Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlKf0h0K5PU), Its spawning network car player which can be controlled by local player. I can make or join server through Network Manager HUD which is provide by the unity.

**I am able to run and connect application on my LAN on different PCs but failed to connect it on other network**. I don't know what are the reasons. Do I need to make or purchase a server for it or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the application over the internet? If so, you'll probably need to redirect the port you're using on your router before this will work

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand "you'll probably need to redirect the port you're using on your router before this will work"

Comment: @hobnob please are you there?

Comment: What happens is that in case you are not directly connected to your modem, if you try to send something from the internet to your specific PC you would need to configure your router to forward that information to your internal IP address. That is called port-forwarding and might be affecting you if I understood your question correctly. Look for it on Google to know more about it. This does not apply if you are directly connected to your modem. In that case you might need to open a port on your firewall. Do this with caution as it can be a severe security risk.

Comment: @rlam12 if port forwarding is hard and opening a port in firewall is risky then what are the other approaches to do this taks.